# Monitoring file copy on external devices

Tags: usb-drive, documents, dlp

> Transferred a personal folder from an external HDD to a USB using my
>   work PC. Just used a simple cut paste method between the two drives,
>   never writing anything to the internal HDD. However, come to find out
>   there were some content sensitive pictures within the folder I was
>   unaware of as it was an older external drive and I wanted to salvage
>   some things before discarding it. Anyhow, I never actually opened the
>   files, so no thumbnail cache was created and I am not too concerned
>   about having any kind of trace files on the PC.

However, I know my company could probably log this event, etc, but is there anyway the could have captured the files within the folder itself that I moved? I am a model employee and am regretting my lack of judgement in this scenario.

Does anyone have any ideas on something I may have missed or if I should be worried. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Corporate technologies to do that** include [Data Loss Prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_loss_prevention_software) (DLP) for example.

But scanning for "hot files" that are not even written on disk, there's a 0.01% chance your employer will log **and** review it.

Comment: Ok thanks. Would you agree with my assessment that nothing was written to the internal HDD in this scenario?

Comment: It depends on your environment and your employer, but basically I'd say yes, I agree.

Comment: Are procedures such as mine usually flagged within an IT organization? I'm sorry if I am a bit paranoid but this could be a very stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: @user3377181 as always it depends.  If you are in a locked down gov org, maybe.  Bank, maybe....  etc,etc

Comment: @ctrldot I am not necessarily concerned if they saw the actual proceed. Even if they happened to go back and look at it through screen shots, all the would see is just me moving a folder from one place to the other. My real concern is if the can copy that folder and access it's contents without me knowing. Your thoughts?

Comment: @user3377181 I can only assume that it is possible,but I have not heard of commercial products specifically doing that. They usually work to block USB / limit USB devices that can be used.

Comment: Ok. Finally, other than thumbnail cache (which I know didn't generate since I never viewed those files in "thumbnail view", and the unlikely chance something was written to pagefile, do you see any other possible concern areas? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Possible, yes, though *very* unlikely.  But I don't know who you work for and what technologies your employer implements.

Comment: Ok. I didn't think so either. I was reading about Spector 360 Document Tracker...is that a tool that could actually save the files?